# Expected pattern error in iOS while using table view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, tuples

I am working on a little application where i need to fetch data from an array of dictionary. Create dynamic sections and rows in it. While accessing array I am getting an error of Expected Pattern. Please help in solving this problem. I facing this problem since last two days.

I am getting error on line: 
let [workCategory:[(portName,portDesc)]] = portfolioData[indexPath.row]!
I have used this line three time and I am getting error overtime.

```
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  tableDemo
    //
    //  Created by User 1 on 03/10/15.
    //  Copyright © 2015 User 1. All rights reserved.
    //

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

let portfolioData = [
    "Websites" :
            [("CDO Group","This portal helps in real estate business"),("Food Truck","This website helps you to find food and Book."),("The Grand Residency","This portal helps you to find your home.")],
    "Applications" : [("The Judefly","This application helps you to select travelling destination."),("The Kindle Ebook","An online eBook Store."),("Nanolux","The technology to next generation.")],
    "Softwares" : [("QPM Agility","This software helps to manage whole organization."),("Nikhil","A softwre to next gen")]]

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        var count = 0
        for variable in portfolioData
        {
            print(variable)
            count++
        }
        return count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        switch section
        {
        case 0 :
            return portfolioData["Websites"]!.count
        case 1 :
            return portfolioData["Applications"]!.count
        default:
            return portfolioData["Softwares"]!.count

        }

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            var count = 0

            if indexPath.section  == 0
            {
                let [workCategory:[(portName,portDesc)]] = portfolioData[indexPath.row]!
                cell.textLabel!.text = portName
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = portDesc
                let variable = "img" + String(count)
                let myImage = UIImage(named: variable)
                cell.imageView?.image = myImage
                count++
            }
            else if indexPath.section == 1
            {
                let [workCategory:[(portName,portDesc)]] = portfolioData[indexPath.row]
                cell.textLabel!.text = portName
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = portDesc
                let variable = "img" + String(count)
                let myImage = UIImage(named: variable)
                cell.imageView?.image = myImage
                count++
            }
            else
            {
                let [workCategory:[(portName,portDesc)]] = portfolioData[indexPath.row]
                cell.textLabel!.text = portName
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = portName
                let variable = "img" + String(count)
                let myImage = UIImage(named: variable)
                cell.imageView?.image = myImage
                count++
            }
        //count = 0
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        if section == 0
        {
            return "Websites"
        }
        else if section == 1
        {
            return "Applications"
        }
        else
        {
            return "Softwares"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `[workCategory:[(portName,portDesc)]]`? Be aware that after `let` keyword you must define constant name and after that you can declare its type